# Is there a way to be able to see more than 6 x-ticks on a graph (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am generating a graph of the members of a discord server at given intervals, however, i can only see 6 of said intervals at a given time whereas the lists that i am using to generate the graphs are 28 intervals.

```
membersList = read_json(ctx, "members_number_list")
        dateList = read_json(ctx, "members_date_list")
        reversed(membersList)
        y = membersList
        x = range(1, len(dateList) + 1)
        my_xticks = dateList
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25, 10))


        ax.plot(x, y, linestyle = "--", color = "r")

        ax.set_xticklabels(my_xticks, rotation=90)
        ax.set_xlabel("Time", fontsize=16)
        ax.set_ylabel("Members", fontsize=16)

        fig.patch.set_facecolor("#2f3136")
        fig.savefig(f"{str(ctx.guild.id)}-membergraph.png")
```

Here is an image of said plot
[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkTLf.png)

Comment: I don't seem to be able to reproduce your issue and using randomly generated data, your code produced the full plot just fine with matplotlib v3.3.2 in a jupyter notebook.  Can you provide some information regarding what version of matplotlib you are using, and what the structure of the data looks like (dateList, membersList).  Eg. Are they string, dates, integers?

Answer (score 0):

I think the key is to use the `ax.set_xticks` method along with setting their labels as you have.

I tried to reproduce your context with a fix as follows:

```py
import datetime
import math
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Generated some fake data to help with visualisation

first_day = datetime(2020,1,1)

membersList = [int(math.sin(x*math.pi/4)) for x in range(28)]
dateList = [first_day+timedelta(days=x) for x in range(28)]

y = membersList
x = range(1, len(dateList) + 1)
my_xticks = dateList
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25, 10))


ax.plot(x, y, linestyle = "--", color = "r")
ax.set_xticks([x+1 for x in range(28)]) # Here is what you needed to add
ax.set_xticklabels(my_xticks, rotation=90)
ax.set_xlabel("Time", fontsize=16)
ax.set_ylabel("Members", fontsize=16)

plt.show()
```

Which gave me something like:
[Plot with all ticks present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnTtb.png)